# Scraping using BS4 and Requests-HTML works only on first page, then ('NoneType' object has no attribute 'find')

Tags: web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests, python-requests-html

I'm new to web scraping using Python and BeautifulSoup and I'm trying to extract car data (model, price, etc.) from a [public site](https://ksa.carswitch.com/en/saudi/used-cars/search) with Requests-HTML. I can successfully output the data I need from page 1, but when I try to go through the rest of the pages using my function getnextpage(soup) with a loop, I get the following error after it outputs the contents and the correct full url of page 1:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\...\PycharmProjects\WebScraping\scrape_test.py", line 40, in <module>
    url = getnextpage(soup)
  File "C:\Users\...\PycharmProjects\WebScraping\scrape_test.py", line 31, in getnextpage
    if not page.find('a', {'class': 'page-number page-number--next page-number--icon disabled'}):
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'find'
```

Followed by

```
None
```

This is most of the code for context:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from requests_html import HTMLSession

s = HTMLSession()
url = 'https://ksa.carswitch.com/en/saudi/used-cars/search'


def getdata(url):
    r = s.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')
    return soup

def scrapesite(soup):
    [code for scraping data]

def getnextpage(soup):
    page = soup.find('div', {'class': 'pagination_navigation'})
    if not page.find('a', {'class': 'page-number page-number--next page-number--icon disabled'}):
        url = 'https://ksa.carswitch.com/' + str(page.find('a', {'class': 'page-number page-number--next page-number--icon'})['href'])
        return url
    else:
        return

while True:
    soup = getdata(url)
    scrapesite(soup)
    url = getnextpage(soup)
    if not url:
        break
    print(url)
```

The idea is to go through the loop to output the data, check if the Next Page button is not disabled, and do it over again after getting the href for the next page. I know this error typically occurs when there's a typo in the class name, but it's accessing the correct div tag contents when I print it.

This is the HTML that I'm accessing:

```
<div class="pagination_navigation">
<a class="page-number page-number--prev page-number--icon disabled" href="javascript:void();" onclick="changePage(0);event.preventDefault();">
Prev. page
</a>
<a class="page-number page-number--next page-number--icon" href="[href for next page]" onclick="changePage(1);event.preventDefault();">
Next page
</a>
</div>
```

I had initially started with requests and lxml, but I was getting a similar error. I decided to switch to Requests-HTML after some research, thinking it was a JavaScript issue, but the same thing happens. I would appreciate any advice. Thanks in advance.

Comment: the problem seems to be that `div.pagination_navigation` was not found. What site are you trying to scrape? Can you tell us which page caused this error?

Comment: Please post a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). The problem is probably like @Driftr95 said, the `div` with class `pagination_navigation` wasn't found. However, for someone to answer your question, please provide a minimal reproducible example.

Comment: @Driftr95 Sure. I've just edited my post to include the website URL. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I modified your code to scrape the final number in the page count, since the website displays it from page 1, and then construct the url's with the knowledge of how many pages there are. You will need to add the scraping logic to the `for` loop:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from requests_html import HTMLSession

s = HTMLSession()
url = 'https://ksa.carswitch.com/en/saudi/used-cars/search'


def getdata(url):
    r = s.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')
    return soup

def scrapesite(soup):
    print('scraped')

def getmaxpage(soup):
    pagination_links = soup.find_all('a', class_='page-number')
    link = pagination_links[-1]
    last_page = int(link.text)
    return last_page

soup = getdata(url)
scrapesite(soup)
max_pages = getmaxpage(soup)
for i in range(max_pages):
    url = 'https://ksa.carswitch.com/en/saudi/used-cars/search?' + 'page=' + str(i + 1)
    #SCRAPING FUNCTION
    print(url)
    soup = getdata(url)
    scrapesite(soup)
```

I am always thankful when websites show the last page from the start:

[image]

Comment: With your code (and my scraping function where you commented), the URL prints correctly on each iteration, but I keep getting the same data from page 1 every time. Then I included soup = getdata(url) followed by my scraping function and all it does is output page 1 content once, then each consecutive URL with no content.

Comment: @greenbananas2 yeah, I didn’t change the code to use the new URL’s, only showed how to construct them. I don’t have access to your scraping functions, but you will need to construct the url and scrape the page with each iteration of the for loop. I have updated my code minimally to include your function in each loop.

Comment: Sorry, looks like I foolishly missed a ? in the url when adding the page numbers. Edited to fix that

Comment: Thank you. Your solution helped me get closer to solving my problem, but for some odd reason it only outputs the first 3 pages of data. On page 4 onward, it prints only the URLs with no data... even though the scrape function is in the loop and worked the first 3 times!