# Selenium not finding specific element by class name, CSS selector, XPATH

Tags: selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

I asked [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77963567/scraping-using-bs4-and-requests-html-works-only-on-first-page-then-nonetype) last month and have yet to find a solution, so I decided to switch to Selenium to see if that would help.

I'm trying to scrape [this site](https://ksa.carswitch.com/en/saudi/used-cars/search) and I've only been able to scrape the first page due to issues the Next button, which refuses to be found no matter what I use as a locator. I'm attempting to check for the string "disabled" in the Next button's class name so my script can tell it hasn't reached the last page yet and can keep scraping. The button can't be found through find_elements or as a single element. This occurs with all elements in the pagination area, so I can't even wriggle my way around this issue. I get an empty string, empty list, or No Such Element exception.

Here is a minimum reproducible example:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument("--headless")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)
driver.implicitly_wait(0.5)

driver.get("https://ksa.carswitch.com/en/saudi/used-cars/search?page=1")

next_page_buttons = driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".page-number--next")
next_button = next_page_buttons[0]
if next_button.text == "":
    print("The element is empty.")
```

A few examples of what I've tried include:

```
#next_page_button = self.driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".page-number--next")

#next_page_button = self.driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, "page-number page-number--next page-number--icon") 

#page_links = self.driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".page-number")
#lastpagelink = page_links[-1]
#last_page = int(lastpagelink.text) #trying to see if it returns last page number to loop through instead. Returns empty string.

#wait = WebDriverWait(self.driver, 100)
#pagination_links = [link.text for link in wait.until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, '.page-number--next')))] #Raised Timeout Exception
#pagination_links = [link.text for link in wait.until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, "//a[@class='page-number page-number--next page-number--icon']")))] #Timeout Exception again
```

...and all other combinations of this. Could this problem have something to do with the style tag? I don't see anything that could affect the elements' visibility.
[image]

I would greatly appreciate any help. Thank you.

Comment: Screenshots of the UI are great, screenshots of code or HTML are not. Please read why [a screenshot of code/HTML is a bad idea](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors). Paste the code/HTML as text and properly format it instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can update the locator for next page button as below

```
//section[contains(@class,'heading show')]//a[contains(text(),'Next page')]
```

You can use below code where we check If Next Page button has disabled attribute in class , if it doesn't then we click next page Button using a JavaScript click and fetch the prices on the next page and continue until button gets disabled. You can mdofiy the code to extract the data as per your need

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager

# Initialize WebDriver
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=Service(ChromeDriverManager().install()))
driver.implicitly_wait(10)
driver.get("https://ksa.carswitch.com/en/saudi/used-cars/search?page=1")

prices = []

def fetch_prices():
    prices_el = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, "//div[@class='title']/span")
    return [el.text for el in prices_el]
    
prices.extend(fetch_prices())

while True:
        next_page_button = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//section[contains(@class,'heading show')]//a[contains(text(),'Next page')]")
        isDisabled="disabled" in  next_page_button.get_attribute("class")
        if isDisabled:
             break
        else: 
            driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", next_page_button)
            prices.extend(fetch_prices())
driver.quit()
print(prices)
```

Comment: This worked for me. Thanks a lot. Do you happen to know why Selenium was not finding it earlier?